# Adding an OpenGL graphics card to a PCI32 only motherboard

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to add a 3D graphics adapter on a PCI32 only server motherboard. All modern graphics adapter are PCI-Express based, what options do I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrox still make PCI video cards

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/g_series/g450pci/
http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/g_series/g550lppci/
http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/p_series/p690pci/